# Helm template syntax when using subcharts?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I asked [Use one Helm chart for ALL microservices?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13379/use-one-helm-chart-for-all-microservices) and now I'm trying to implement the answer I accepted, i.e., using sub charts. (Note: If there's a **better** answer for that post, please put it in that post, not here.)

Per the answer I accepted, I have the following directory structure

```
my-deployment-repo/
|- base-microservice/
   |- templates/
      |- deployment.yml
      |- service.yml
   |- Chart.yaml
   |- values.yaml
|- myapp/
   |- Chart.yaml
   |- values.yaml
```

`base-microservice/values.yaml` file has

```
image:
  name: ""
  version: ""
  repository: 01234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: ""

service:
  type: NodePort
  port: 5000

# More key/value pairs defined
```

`myapp/Chart.yaml` has

```
apiVersion: v2
name: myapp
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes
...
dependencies:
  - alias: my-microservice-1
    name: base-microservice
    version: "0.1.0"
    repository: file://../base-microservice
  - alias: my-microservice-2
    name: base-microservice
    version: "0.1.0"
    repository: file://../base-microservice
```

`myapp/values.yaml` simply has this because I want `myapp` to use ALL the values in `base-microservice/values.yaml` except for the values I provide here.

```
my-microservice-1:
  image:
    name: foo
    version: 1.2.3

my-microservice-2:
  image:
    name: bar
    version: 4.5.6
```

So now when I do a...

```
$ helm update ./myapp
$ helm install myapp myapp/
```

...I want to be able to get, for example, the deployment for the alias `microservice-1`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
...
  template:
  ...
    spec:
    ...
      containers:
      - name: foo # image name for microservice-1 alias
        # These are from the different values.yaml files
        # <repository from base-microservice>/<image name from myapp>:v<ersion from myapp>
        image: 01234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foo:1.2.3
```

IOW, what should the `base-microserivce/templates/deployment.yaml` syntax be to...

- `spec.template.spec.containers.name: {{ what should be here to produce "foo" }}` and
- `spec.template.spec.containers.image: {{ what should be here to produce "01234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foo:1.2.3" }}`

I hope that makes sense. TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the template file is eventually rendered, `.Values` will be [a subset specific to this subchart](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#scope-dependencies-and-values).  So in your template code, just use `.Values` the same way you would if it were a standalone chart.

```yaml
containers:
  - name: foo {{-/* not templated */}}
    image: {{ with .Values.image }}{{ .repository }}/{{ .name }}:{{ .version }}{{ end }}
```

I've intentionally chosen to not template `name` in this example.  A container name is only useful in a couple of very specific contexts (to review `kubectl logs` in a multi-container Pod, for example) and IME it's much easier to set it to a fixed name than to try to template it.  You could use `{{ .Values.image.name }}` here as well if you wanted to.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your first statement turned on the light bulb for me. :)